# 10.8.5 - How to configure Chrome to save "0" pages in history?

Tags: google-chrome, history

I can not find a setting concerning history other than to Delete All, etc.

How do I to stop Chrome from saving all pages visited?

Default to 100 sites vs. 10.

Comment: Your question is not clear, are you asking "How to stop chrome from keeping track of all the web pages you visited" ?.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question right, you don't want google chrome to save any tracks after you visit a site on your computer.

For that purpose you can use **Incognito Mode** which won't save any cache of the pages you've visited or any entries in the history.